# Is it acceptable to subclass c_void_p in ctypes?

Tags: python, ctypes

I am interfacing with a library that returns opaque pointers. Is it acceptable to subclass c_void_p to represent this in ctypes and provide for type checking for this particular flavor of c_void_p?

Comment: Are you going to do type checking on the *return values* of the library functions?  Or what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: One function returns a c_void_p and another function accepts it as its argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to do this type checking might be to create some arbitrary `ctypes.Structure`

```
class _Opaque(ctypes.Structure):
    pass
```

Declare the return type of the relevant functions to be a pointer to this structure

```
lib.f.restype = ctypes.POINTER(_Opaque)
```

and either the argument type of a function which accepts this kind of pointer again:

```
lib.g.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(_Opaque)]
```

Now, `ctypes` ensures that the parameter to `g` is a pointer that was returned by `f` before.  (Note that I used a leading `_` to mark `_Opaque` for uses in this module only.)

Comment: I found the snippet in the documentation. It is OK to subclass a ctypes primitive, although some behavior is not inherited. http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes-fundamental-data-types-2

Comment: While this work for a limited scenario, it prevent from having member function to the class `_Opaque` since really ctypes makes it an `int`. I hope there is something nicer to handle opaque type using ctypes.

Comment: @malat: The data is opaque, so member functions on the class seem rather pointless.  You are likely trying to solve a different problem than the OP in this question.

Comment: @SvenMarnach since API uses opaque pointer, all function takes this pointer as -say- first member, which make it a pseudo-object oriented API.

Comment: @malat You are right, that methods forwarding to C code could make sense on the opaque class.  I don't know how to make this work (and unfortunately don't have time to investigate).